# My AffineTransformation has gaps between pixels

Tags: java, affinetransform

First I want to say that I am not using the **AffineTransform** class that Oracle made. I am doing my "own" AffineTransform. Why? I am making a pixel engine and I couldn't find any other solution. So I began looking a bit at *Wikipedia* and how matrices work. I then watched *javidx9's* [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxwLN2blwbQ) at how to implement it. I got it working. Rotation,reflection,shear etc worked fine but I got a pixel gap. *Javidx9* mentioned this in his video and he solved the problem. I tried his solution but I got an **"ArrayOutOfIndex error"** when doing reflection,rotation and shear. I have been trying to solve the issue but I just can't understand what I am doing due to the complex code. That's why I am here! I need **your** help!

I got it working like this (with gaps):

[GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmtxW.jpg)

The code I use for the transformation with gaps is the following:

**Render the image with a matrix**

```
        for (int x = 0; x < image2.getWidth(); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < image2.getHeight(); y++)
        {
            
            
            matrixLast.forward(x,y);
            renderer.setPixel((int)matrixLast.getNx(),(int) matrixLast.getNy(), image2.getPixels()[x+y*image2.getWidth()], null, 255);
        }
    }
```

However as you can see you need more information than that. **I also made a "Matrix3x3" class, here are the important methods/functions**:

```
    public static void Identity(Matrix3x3 mat)
{
    mat.matrix[0][0] = 1.0f; mat.matrix[1][0] = 0.0f; mat.matrix[2][0] = 0.0f;
    mat.matrix[0][1] = 0.0f; mat.matrix[1][1] = 1.0f; mat.matrix[2][1] = 0.0f;
    mat.matrix[0][2] = 0.0f; mat.matrix[1][2] = 0.0f; mat.matrix[2][2] = 1.0f;
}

public static void Translate(Matrix3x3 mat, float ox, float oy)
{
    mat.matrix[0][0] = 1.0f; mat.matrix[1][0] = 0.0f; mat.matrix[2][0] = ox;
    mat.matrix[0][1] = 0.0f; mat.matrix[1][1] = 1.0f; mat.matrix[2][1] = oy;
    mat.matrix[0][2] = 0.0f;    mat.matrix[1][2] = 0.0f;    mat.matrix[2][2] = 1.0f;
}

public static void Rotate(Matrix3x3 mat, float degrees)
{
    double fTheta = Math.toRadians(degrees);
    mat.matrix[0][0] = (float)Math.cos(fTheta);  mat.matrix[1][0] = (float)-Math.sin(fTheta); mat.matrix[2][0] = 0.0f;
    mat.matrix[0][1] = (float)Math.sin(fTheta); mat.matrix[1][1] = (float)Math.cos(fTheta); mat.matrix[2][1] = 0.0f;
    mat.matrix[0][2] = 0.0f;                     mat.matrix[1][2] = 0.0f;        mat.matrix[2][2] = 1.0f;
}

public static void Scale(Matrix3x3 mat, float sx, float sy)
{
    mat.matrix[0][0] = sx;   mat.matrix[1][0] = 0.0f; mat.matrix[2][0] = 0.0f;
    mat.matrix[0][1] = 0.0f; mat.matrix[1][1] = sy;   mat.matrix[2][1] = 0.0f;
    mat.matrix[0][2] = 0.0f;    mat.matrix[1][2] = 0.0f;    mat.matrix[2][2] = 1.0f;
}

public static void Shear(Matrix3x3 mat, float sx, float sy)
{   
    mat.matrix[0][0] = 1.0f; mat.matrix[1][0] = sx;   mat.matrix[2][0] = 0.0f;
    mat.matrix[0][1] = sy;   mat.matrix[1][1] = 1.0f; mat.matrix[2][1] = 0.0f;
    mat.matrix[0][2] = 0.0f;    mat.matrix[1][2] = 0.0f;    mat.matrix[2][2] = 1.0f;
}

public static void Reflection(Matrix3x3 mat) {
    
    mat.matrix[0][0] = -1.0f; mat.matrix[1][0] = 0;   mat.matrix[2][0] = 0.0f;
    mat.matrix[0][1] = 0;   mat.matrix[1][1] = 1.0f; mat.matrix[2][1] = 0.0f;
    mat.matrix[0][2] = 0.0f;    mat.matrix[1][2] = 0.0f;    mat.matrix[2][2] = 1.0f;
}

public void forward(float inX, float inY) { //Ingen aning vad denna gör
    float outX,outY;
    
    outX = (inX * this.matrix[0][0]) + (inY * this.matrix[1][0]) + this.matrix[2][0];   
    outY = (inX * this.matrix[0][1]) + (inY * this.matrix[1][1]) + this.matrix[2][1];
    
    this.ny = outY;
    this.nx = outX;
}
```

In the "render" code as you can see above you see that there is a "matrixLast" in there. **Here is how I got that one (they are defined elsewhere as for example: "Matrix3x3 name;"):**

```
    Matrix3x3.Translate(matrixFinal3, -image2.getWidth() / 2, -image2.getHeight() / 2);
    
    Matrix3x3.Rotate(matrixFinal2,rotation);            //Rotation och shear är det något fel på.
    
    matrixSum = Matrix3x3.multiplyMatrix(matrixFinal2, matrixFinal3);
    Matrix3x3.Translate(matrixFinal, 700, 600);
    
    matrixLast = Matrix3x3.multiplyMatrix(matrixFinal, matrixSum);
    
    matrixInv = Matrix3x3.invert(matrixLast);
```

The issue I am having is basically that I am trying to fix the "gaps". I tried **Javidx9's solution** which changes the render code to the following (Utils.getMaximum() returns the largest number and the opposite for Utils.getMinimum() ):

```
    float ex,ey,sx,sy;
    
    
    
    matrixLast.forward(0f, 0f); 
    sx = matrixLast.getNx();
    ex = matrixLast.getNx();
    sy = matrixLast.getNy();
    ey = matrixLast.getNy();
            
    matrixLast.forward((float) image2.getWidth(), (float) image2.getHeight());      
    sx = Utils.getMinimum(sx, matrixLast.getNx()); sy = Utils.getMinimum(sy, matrixLast.getNy());
    ex  = Utils.getMaximum(ex, matrixLast.getNx()); ey = Utils.getMaximum(ey, matrixLast.getNy());
    
    matrixLast.forward(0f, (float) image2.getHeight());     
    sx = Utils.getMinimum(sx, matrixLast.getNx()); sy = Utils.getMinimum(sy, matrixLast.getNy());
    ex  = Utils.getMaximum(ex, matrixLast.getNx()); ey = Utils.getMaximum(ey, matrixLast.getNy());
    
    matrixLast.forward((float) image2.getWidth(), 0f);      
    sx = Utils.getMinimum(sx, matrixLast.getNx()); sy = Utils.getMinimum(sy, matrixLast.getNy());
    ex  = Utils.getMaximum(ex, matrixLast.getNx()); ey = Utils.getMaximum(ey, matrixLast.getNy());
    
    for(int x = (int)sx; x < (int)ex; x++) {
        
        for(int y = (int)sy; y < (int)ey; y++) {
            
            matrixInv.forward(x,y);
            
            
            
                    
            
            renderer.setPixel(x, y, image2.getPixels()[(int)(matrixInv.getNx() + 0.5) + (int)(matrixInv.getNy() + 0.5) * image2.getWidth()], null, 255);
            
        }
    }
```

He also added an **invert** method:

```
    public static Matrix3x3 invert(Matrix3x3 matIn) {
    
    float det = matIn.matrix[0][0] * (matIn.matrix[1][1] * matIn.matrix[2][2] - matIn.matrix[1][2] * matIn.matrix[2][1]) -
            matIn.matrix[1][0] * (matIn.matrix[0][1] * matIn.matrix[2][2] - matIn.matrix[2][1] * matIn.matrix[0][2]) +
            matIn.matrix[2][0] * (matIn.matrix[0][1] * matIn.matrix[1][2] - matIn.matrix[1][1] * matIn.matrix[0][2]);

        float idet = 1.0f / det;
        Matrix3x3 matOut = new Matrix3x3();
        
        matOut.matrix[0][0] = (matIn.matrix[1][1] * matIn.matrix[2][2] - matIn.matrix[1][2] * matIn.matrix[2][1]) * idet;
        matOut.matrix[1][0] = (matIn.matrix[2][0] * matIn.matrix[1][2] - matIn.matrix[1][0] * matIn.matrix[2][2]) * idet;
        matOut.matrix[2][0] = (matIn.matrix[1][0] * matIn.matrix[2][1] - matIn.matrix[2][0] * matIn.matrix[1][1]) * idet;
        matOut.matrix[0][1] = (matIn.matrix[2][1] * matIn.matrix[0][2] - matIn.matrix[0][1] * matIn.matrix[2][2]) * idet;
        matOut.matrix[1][1] = (matIn.matrix[0][0] * matIn.matrix[2][2] - matIn.matrix[2][0] * matIn.matrix[0][2]) * idet;
        matOut.matrix[2][1] = (matIn.matrix[0][1] * matIn.matrix[2][0] - matIn.matrix[0][0] * matIn.matrix[2][1]) * idet;
        matOut.matrix[0][2] = (matIn.matrix[0][1] * matIn.matrix[1][2] - matIn.matrix[0][2] * matIn.matrix[1][1]) * idet;
        matOut.matrix[1][2] = (matIn.matrix[0][2] * matIn.matrix[1][0] - matIn.matrix[0][0] * matIn.matrix[1][2]) * idet;
        matOut.matrix[2][2] = (matIn.matrix[0][0] * matIn.matrix[1][1] - matIn.matrix[0][1] * matIn.matrix[1][0]) * idet;
    
    return matOut;
    
}
```

Here is when he totally lost me, it got too complex and I don't know how to troubleshoot it due to me not knowing exactly what the code does. His solution gave me an **ArrayOutOfIndex**error but only when doing reflections,rotations and shear:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -9 out of bounds for length 589824
at com.dubstepzedd.gameengine.gamemanager.GameManager.render(GameManager.java:112)
at com.dubstepzedd.gameengine.GameContainer.loop(GameContainer.java:94)
at com.dubstepzedd.gameengine.GameContainer.run(GameContainer.java:48)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
at com.dubstepzedd.gameengine.GameContainer.start(GameContainer.java:40)
at com.dubstepzedd.gameengine.gamemanager.GameManager.main(GameManager.java:178)
```

I have no clue why this is happening. If someone has any advice on how to approach the "gap" situation differently or what is wrong with the code please comment or post a question

**UPDATE**

Here is the how it acts when I added getPixel():

[Link to GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HyCD.jpg)

The code added to the Image class:

```
public int getPixel(int x, int y) {
    
    if(0 <= x && x < this.width && 0 <= y && y < this.height) {
        return pixels[x+y*this.width];
    }
    else {
        return Color.black.getRGB();    
    }
}
```

Comment: @akuzminykh Good question! What I mean by that is that I have a difficult time understanding how the invert works. I also don’t really get the Borderbox solution that was provided by javidx9. It’s difficult for me to understand the logic behind his solution. Implementing his solution into Java isnt difficult. However troubleshooting his solution was not easy.

Comment: I also don’t understand how the solution works for him but not for me? Especially when the first with ”gaps” worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a pixel that's outside the original image here:

```
image2.getPixels()[(int)(matrixInv.getNx() + 0.5) + (int)(matrixInv.getNy() + 0.5) * image2.getWidth()]
```

I would recommend adding a method to your image class that returns the pixel at a x/y position, if x and y are in range, and a default color if not:

```
// add to image class:
int getPixel(int x, int y) {
    if (0 <= x && x < width && 0 <= y && y < height) {
        return pixelData[x + width*y];
    } else {
        return backgroundColor;
    }
}
```

Use this method instead of array lookups - for example

```
for(int x = (int)sx; x < (int)ex; x++) {
    for(int y = (int)sy; y < (int)ey; y++) {
        matrixInv.forward(x,y);
        int pixel = image2.getPixel((int)(matrixInv.getNx() + 0.5, (int)(matrixInv.getNy() + 0.5))
        renderer.setPixel(x, y, pixel);
    }
}
```

Comment: I added so that when a pixel is outside the screen it will be ignored, however that was implemented a long time ago. Is that what you mean?

Comment: It works for scaling, why wouldn’t it work for rotation? I mean if scaling doesnt output the error why would rotation do it?

Comment: when you rotate, the rectangle is no longer axis-aligned and you are going to access pixels outside the image. I guess your `Utils.getMaximum` and `Utils.getMinimum` methods do the correct thing as long as the rectangle stay axis-aligned but you need a different solution for rotation

Comment: My Utils.getMaximum is very simple: if(number1 > number2) return number1; else return number2;

Comment: How would you adapt it to rotation? Any websites to recommend?

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood. The problem is not that the pixels will be outside of *screen*. The problem is that the pixel you are looking up in the rotated image is out of bounds of the *source image*. That's why you need to add a function to look up pixels to your image class.

Comment: I get that the issue isn’t that the pixels are outside the Frame. Its the image pixel data that is the issue as you said. So You are saying that the solution is to loop through the pixels in a function? How will I know which pixel to draw? I am confused. If I make a function to loop through the image pixels, what purpose Will it have? I still dont know which pixel to draw do I?

Comment: You draw the pixel `(matrixInv.getNx(), matrixInv.getNy())` on the pixel `(x,y)` - you already have code that does this. I'm not really sure what you find confusing

Comment: But if I get the pixel matrixInv.getNx(),matrixInv.getNy() of the source image I will get ArrayOutOfIndex right? The code in my question has the following in the ”render” code: image2.getPixels()[matrixInv.getNx() + matrixInv.getNy() * image2.getWidth()]. This gets the color value of the pixel at matrixInv.getNx() and matrixInv.getNy(). Am I not doing what you are asking?

Comment: Never mind, I am tired. I see that you have an example in your answer. I am sorry :/ I will try it out!

Comment: I added the getPixel() code you provided and used it. However it gave a weird result. I will update the question

Comment: That's an interesting result, it looks like there may be something wrong with the rotation matrix or with how it's inverted. Inverting a rotation matrix is easy: it's just a rotation in the opposite direction

Comment: I got the invert method from javidx9's github. It was difficult to understand so I just copied it: https://github.com/OneLoneCoder/olcPixelGameEngine/blob/master/Videos/OneLoneCoder_PGE_SpriteTransforms.cpp. I try to understand everything after, it's easier to understand when it works. I get the same result with Identity etc.

Comment: I got it working, I misstyped as always... Thanks again Joni! You save me every single time... It's almost embarrasing hehe